# scrlayer-scrpage: line with relative length

Tags: koma-script, scrpage2, scrlayer-scrpage

To get a centered line with a length of `.25\textwidth` above the page number, until now I used the `scrpage2` package and this command:

```
\setfootsepline[.25\textwidth]{.4pt}
```

This is deprecated now, so I'd like to switch to `scrlayer-scrpage`, but the equivalent

```
\usepackage[footsepline=:.25\textwidth]{scrlayer-scrpage}
```

throws errors. If I insert an absolute value like `5cm` just for testing the line is also **flush left** instead of centered.

How can I get the behaviour of `scrpage2`'s `\setfootsepline` command with `scrlayer-scrpage`?

## MWE

This shows what I want and – commented out – what I tried.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setfootsepline[0.25\textwidth]{0.4pt}
% \usepackage[footsepline=:.25\textwidth]{scrlayer-scrpage}
% \usepackage[footsepline=:5cm]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\begin{document}test page\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{footsepline=:.25\textwidth,clines}
\begin{document}test page\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[footsepline=:\the\textwidth*25/100,clines]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\begin{document}test page\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[footsepline=:\the\textwidth/4,clines]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\begin{document}test page\end{document}
```

Note that a length in the optional argument of a package or class will be expanded complettly. So I would suggest to use `\KOMAoptions` for setting the width of the rule.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that solves the first problem, however the line isn't centered (as with `scrpage2`) this way. As I just figured out, `\KOMAoptions{clines}` will do the trick.